# google bq python client - session id for load job

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to write some data into bigquery using the `client.load_table_from_file` method but would like to be able to run a query on it before committing the change.
E.g.:

```py
load_job = client.load_table_from_file(df,**kwargs)
client.query('update query')
# commit
```

Seems like sessions are available when running queries (see: https://dev.to/stack-labs/bigquery-transactions-over-multiple-queries-with-sessions-2ll5) but unable to find similar functionality for `LoadJob`s. I can see that `LoadJobConfig` has a `session_info` parameter, but this gives `None` by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `client.query()` method to run a query on the table after loading it. Here is an example:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
)

with open("/path/to/file.csv", "rb") as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(
        source_file,
        table_id,
        location="US",  # Must match the destination dataset location.
        job_config=job_config,
    )

job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

sql = """
    SELECT name, SUM(number) as count
    FROM `your-project.your_dataset.your_table`
    GROUP BY name
"""
query_job = client.query(sql)  # Make an API request.
rows = query_job.result()  # Waits for query to finish.

for row in rows:
    print("{}: {}".format(row["name"], row["count"]))
```

Comment: but this way data is written, so a dedup process needs to be run. Is it possible to query the "job", i.e. before job.result() which commits data to BQ?